# How do I code an L2 Norm for a Finite Difference Scheme?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

I have to compute the L2 norm of a Finite Difference Scheme applied to a second order differential equation.  I set up the code to perform the Scheme with n = 20 and n = 200, and my input is

```
For[i = 1, i < n, i++, 
 u[i + 1] = (2*h^2 x[i]^2 + 2*h^2 u[i] + x[i]*h*u[i - 1] + 4*u[i] - 
      2*u[i - 1])/(2 + x[i]*h);
```

I know the formula for the L2 norm is ||U||_Uh = h*Sum[[u[i]^2, {0, n}], but I don't know how to get Mathematica to calculate the sum for me with each of the 20 or 200 u values.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should type all of mathematical formula and explain your calculate process.

Comment: I've typed everything I know how to do.  I'm not having trouble performing the FDS, just writing the code to find the L2 Norm.